# Using latexmk run commands after xelatex is run using the -no-pdf argument so pdf not corrupted

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xelatex, latexmk

I have a `latexmkrc` file that looks like this:

```
$xelatex = 'xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -synctex=1 %O %S; (sleep 10) && (test -f "%Z%R.synctex.gz") && (cp "%Z%R.synctex.gz" "%R.synctex.gz"); (test -f "%D") && (cp "%D" "%R.pdf")';
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S; (test -f "%Z%R.synctex.gz") && (cp "%Z%R.synctex.gz" "%R.synctex.gz"); (test -f "%D") && (cp "%D" "%R.pdf")';
$out_dir = '/tmp';
```

Latexmk automatically adds `-no-pdf` since the `%O` is specified. If this is the case, then it seems the commands after the xelatex command are run before the conversion of the extended dvi to pdf using `xdvipdfmx`. My .pdf file is always corrupted in the local folder but if I open it in the /tmp folder it is fine. Is there a way to run these copy commands after the command for `xdvipdfmx` when using the `-no-pdf`.

Here is an image of what happens at the end. This is run after the copy commands above are already run. The pdf file copied is always corrupted.

[image: command line output showing the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question, the problem is that the definitions given in the question assume that `xelatex` is used by `latexmk` to make a pdf file.  In fact, `latexmk` arranges for `xelatex` to make an xdv file, and then calls `xdvpdfmx` to make the pdf file from the xdv file. (The reason that `latexmk` does this is that for a graphics intensive documents, this can result in substantial shortening of run time if multiple runs of `xelatex` are needed.)

A suitable solution is to redefine also the command for the xdv-to-pdf conversion as follows

```
$xelatex = 'xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S; (test -f "%Z%R.synctex.gz") && (cp "%Z%R.synctex.gz" "%R.synctex.gz")';
$xdvipdfmx = 'xdvipdfmx -o %D %S; (test -f "%D") && (cp "%D" "%R.pdf")';
```

(Note some of the lines in the code sample are long, so scroll the box to see all of the codes.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `latexmk` to run your document in a temporary directory and then convincing it to copy the result back to your working folder seems unnecessarily complicate. I suggest to use [ltx2any](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) instead. This is an automation tool like latexmk, just with the advantage that it will use a temporary folder by default and automatically deal with copying the pdf and synctex files back.

Usage:

```
ltx2any -synctex -e xelatex filename
```